How to make recursive functions in python?
I'm trying to create a short python 3 function that takes 2 classes of items and spits out an inventory list. One class is just plain objects (let's call them 'item' class) and the other is an object that contains other objects (I've been calling them 'containers'). The problem arises when I try to print every single object (both classes) in the inventory. This includes items inside of containers. It should look something like this:
You are carrying:
an apple
a basket, containing:
 an orange
 a glass bottle, containing:
  a quantity of water

My current code does this manually with basically:
if(object.type=='container'):
 for object1 in object.inventory:
  print(object.name)
  if(object1.type=='container'):
   for object2 in object1:
    print(object2.name)

and so on, which is obviously atrocious. How could I make this function theoretically limitless?
-I am new to python so simple explanations for solutions are always appreciated!-

To make a recursive function, you must first make a function - and you have shown us only bare code, not in a function.  You can call a function from inside itself, in exactly the same way you'd call it from outside.

Something like the following should work. I avoided the term "object" because that is a built in Python term and consequently kind of reserved.
Furthermore you had two variants: for ... in object.inventory and for ... in object1, so I wasn't sure how exactly your things are nested. Please adjust the code if needed.
def print_items(container):
    for item in container:
        print(item.name)
        if item.type == "container":
            print_items(item)  # the next iterable should go in here


# then use the function on the outermost container
print_items(outermost_container)


Hi! The variation is due to me trying to nest it. The goal would be to not need multiple 'object' layers, and whenever the code encounters a container it would print all the things inside no matter what. I don't know if this is possible, honestly.

It is possible. I was referring to the exact syntax. You had ... object.inventory and ... object1 as the iterable containers, so I was not sure how your object structure looks. My suggested answer needs the next deeper nesting level at print_items(item) if the item is a container. It might be print_items(item.inventory) with your syntax.

Recursion is a concept where a function calls itself to solve subproblems of the same type as the larger original problem, which perfectly suits your requirement to print items and their contained items to any level of nesting.
With classes (recommended)
Let's showcase a basic setup in Python to help us visualize and implement the solution, using classes to represent the entities, and a recursive function to print the inventory:
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Container(Item):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.contents = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.contents.append(item)

def print_inventory(items, level=0):
    indent = " " * level
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, Container): # is a container
            print(f"{indent}{item.name}, containing:")
            print_inventory(item.contents, level + 1)
        else: # is an item
            print(f"{indent}{item.name}")


Example usage:
apple = Item("an apple")
orange = Item("an orange")
water = Item("a quantity of water")

glass_bottle = Container("a glass bottle")
glass_bottle.add_item(water)

basket = Container("a basket")
basket.add_item(orange)
basket.add_item(glass_bottle)

inventory = [apple, basket]
print("You are carrying:")
print_inventory(inventory)

With lists and dictionaries
If you prefer to handle this without defining classes and using a simpler data structure like a list or a dictionary, here's an example of managing the inventory using a recursive approach with dictionaries:
def print_inventory(items, level=0):
    indent - " " * level * 2
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, dict): # is a container
            for name, contents in item.items():
                print(f"{indent}{name}, containing:")
                print_inventory(contents, level + 1)
        else: # is an item
            print(f"{indent}{item}")


Example usage
inventory = [
    "an apple",
    {"a basket, containing:": [
        "an orange",
        {"a glass bottle, containing:" [
            "a quantity of water"
        ]}
    ]}
]

print("You are carrying:")
print_inventory(inventory)

